# Pay Swedish Burial Fee (Begravningsavgift) when just moved to Sweden?

Tags: income-tax, tax-deduction, sweden

I moved to Sweden during 2019 and I am now doing my Swedish tax declaration for the 1st time (related to the '19 income).

I read here ([Skatteverket Begravningsavgift](https://www.skatteverket.se/privat/skatter/arbeteochinkomst/skattetabeller/begravningsavgift.4.1ee2ea81054cf37b1c800030.html)) that this fee is paid by those registered in Sweden on 1 November of the previous year (which would be 2018 for me).

It seems like, at least for this first-year income declaration, I should NOT pay this fee, am I correct?

Is there any other fee that people who just moved to Sweden should NOT pay?

Thanks ;)

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're asking. Are you objecting to the fee and trying to get people to agree with you, or are you asking whether you have to pay the fee or not?

Comment: I am asking whether I understood correctly and, therefore, I should not pay that fee. I am just starting to read some Swedish and I am not sure about the content of that page. People I spoke with do not know either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. If you were registered as living in Sweden ("folkbokförd") after November 1st, 2018, you won't (shouldn't) have to pay the burial fee for the income year 2019.

The amount you have to pay as burial fee is pre-filled and printed separately on the declaration papers (or on Skatteverket's web page), and should be either zero or simply not listed at all for you.

If you see it listed with an amount other than zero, send an e-mail to servicejouren@skatteverket.se and ask them why.